# Find integration boundaries by comparing two data sets

Tags: mathematical-optimization, dataset

EDIT:

## the mathematica problem:

My spectra are two 1-D lists of numbers (which I will copy at the end of this message), and so as to be able to integrate the narrow-slit-data, I created an interpolation function in the following way

- first I smooth the data set with a Gaussian function (so as to simulate the spectral resolution of my apparatus):

  ```
  σ = 0.05;

  convslit = ListConvolve[h Table[Exp[-s^2/σ^2]/(σ Sqrt[2π]), {s, -17, 17}], 
    zerotwentyfivemmslit[[All, 2]]];

  NMinimize[{Sqrt[Mean[MapThread[(#1-#2)^2&,zerotwentyfivemmslit[[18;;234,2]], 
    convslit}]]]}, {h}]

   h1 = h /. %[[2]]
  ```
- I then create an interpolation function for this data

  ```
  f1 := Interpolation[convslit /. {h -> h1}, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
  ```
- as well as for the wider slit data (note that I want both my data sets to be of the same `Length[]` - the first one is shortened by the smoothing process, hence the selection of elements below) - $s=3mm$:

  ```
  f3 := Interpolation[threemmslit[[18 ;; 234, 2]],InterpolationOrder -> 1]
  ```

I then proceed to integrate the first function `f1[x]` and compare it with the second function `f3[x]` at a certain value of `x`: I want Mathematica to find the bounds of the integral for me so as to make the spectral density thus calculated equal the spectral density $R(\lambda)$ (`f3[x]`):

```
tableα = Table[{λ, 218.199 + λ*.2,Quiet@Minimize[{Total[f3[λ]-1/(α s025)
  Integrate[f1[x], {x, λ - (α s3)/2, λ + (α s3)/2}]]}, α]}, {λ, 1, 217, 1}];
```

and I do so for all `x` in my data set.

Intuitively, I would expect the $\alpha$ found by Mathematica to be identical at each point, and of the order of $10^{-6}$ (because it is a scaling factor from the mm size of the slit to the nm range of the spectrum). Also, by using `Minimize` in such a way, I would expect the function to try and make $R(\lambda)-\int_{\Delta\lambda}R_0(\lambda')d\lambda'$ equal 0. That is I would expect it to make the integral equal the number returned by $R(\lambda)$.

For example, I would expect

```
In[99]:= f3[1]
Out[99]= 628
```

And

```
In[102]:= (1/(α s025) \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(λ - \*FractionBox[\(α\ s3\), \(2\)]\), \(λ+\*FractionBox[\(α\ s3\), \(2\)]\)]\(f1[x] \[DifferentialD]x\)\)) /. {λ -> 1, α -> a1 = α /. tableα[[1, 3, 2]]}
```

to be equal. And instead I get

```
During evaluation of In[102]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmvali: The integration endpoint -2.475*10^7 in dimension 1 lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

During evaluation of In[102]:= InterpolatingFunction::dmvali: The integration endpoint 2.4750000999999996`*^7 in dimension 1 lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

Out[102]= -3.71242*10^9
```

I don't understand how to use `Minimize` to achieve what I want, or which other function to use. In particular I don't understand why `Minimize` doesn't return the same $\alpha$ for each `x` (which one can check by evaluating the table command above). How should I proceed?

## The physics background

Here is the drill:

I am acquiring data with a spectrometer in front of which there is a monochromator box (a dispersive grating surrounded by a couple of mirrors that allows for selecting the wavelength that I probe with my spectrometer). I am trying to calculate the transmission of my spectrum through the exit slit of that box.

What I do experimentally is that I let the light in the monochromator box through an entrance slit of set width, and collect the output light on the spectrometer through an exit slit of which I control the width (aperture size in one dimension). I want to compare the spectrum acquired with a very narrow slit width with that obtained for the widest possible slit width and find how they scale. The scaling factor $\alpha$ will allow me to calculate the transmission. Here is how:

With the narrowest slit width achievable ($s_0=0.25 mm$), I acquire a spectrum
$$
R_0(\lambda)=\frac{S(\lambda)}{\alpha s_0}\alpha s_0
$$
where $S(\lambda)$ is the instrument limited spectral density. In other words, this $S(\lambda)$ is the one-dimensional list of data points that my spectrometer outputs and that I smooth with a Gaussian function (that models the resolution of my spectrometer over this range of wavelength, taken to be $\sigma=0.05nm$).

I then want to compare this $R_0(\lambda)$ spectrum with the spectrum acquired with a broader slit, which is done via
$$
\Delta\lambda R (\lambda) = \int_{\Delta\lambda}R_0(\lambda')d\lambda'
$$
where $\Delta\lambda=\alpha s$. So what I have to do is to fit my narrow slit spectrum to the wide slit spectrum and find $\alpha$ (all the rest is known).

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications, comments, and thanks in advance for your help!

## DATA for this problem

```
threemmslit = {{214.999`, 68}, {215.199`, 75}, {215.398`, 
99}, {215.599`, 101}, {215.799`, 110}, {215.998`, 113}, {216.199`,
 125}, {216.399`, 130}, {216.598`, 138}, {216.799`, 
107}, {216.999`, 127}, {217.198`, 150}, {217.398`, 
173}, {217.599`, 195}, {217.799`, 254}, {217.998`, 
313}, {218.199`, 448}, {218.399`, 628}, {218.598`, 
737}, {218.798`, 1004}, {218.999`, 1162}, {219.199`, 
1430}, {219.399`, 1678}, {219.598`, 1914}, {219.798`, 
2108}, {219.999`, 2198}, {220.199`, 2524}, {220.398`, 
2723}, {220.598`, 2943}, {220.799`, 3186}, {220.999`, 
3708}, {221.199`, 4183}, {221.399`, 4936}, {221.598`, 
5898}, {221.798`, 7075}, {221.999`, 8656}, {222.199`, 
10355}, {222.399`, 12313}, {222.599`, 14781}, {222.798`, 
17322}, {222.998`, 20126}, {223.198`, 23798}, {223.399`, 
26914}, {223.599`, 30602}, {223.799`, 33860}, {223.999`, 
37471}, {224.199`, 40773}, {224.399`, 43871}, {224.598`, 
45934}, {224.798`, 48619}, {224.998`, 51557}, {225.198`, 
54117}, {225.398`, 57475}, {225.598`, 61834}, {225.799`, 
67151}, {225.999`, 72663}, {226.199`, 78363}, {226.399`, 
84742}, {226.599`, 90942}, {226.799`, 98306}, {226.999`, 
104499}, {227.199`, 111187}, {227.399`, 117281}, {227.599`, 
123983}, {227.799`, 129698}, {227.999`, 135525}, {228.199`, 
140942}, {228.399`, 144869}, {228.599`, 148032}, {228.799`, 
150883}, {228.999`, 155294}, {229.199`, 161622}, {229.398`, 
167875}, {229.598`, 177732}, {229.798`, 186423}, {229.998`, 
198339}, {230.198`, 210429}, {230.398`, 222737}, {230.599`, 
235357}, {230.799`, 245571}, {230.999`, 255750}, {231.199`, 
265599}, {231.399`, 276725}, {231.599`, 285735}, {231.798`, 
294768}, {231.998`, 305695}, {232.198`, 316322}, {232.399`, 
325110}, {232.599`, 333008}, {232.799`, 341489}, {232.999`, 
348185}, {233.198`, 352357}, {233.398`, 357305}, {233.599`, 
363394}, {233.799`, 371067}, {233.999`, 380632}, {234.198`, 
389815}, {234.398`, 400643}, {234.599`, 412805}, {234.799`, 
421211}, {234.999`, 431654}, {235.198`, 440687}, {235.398`, 
448523}, {235.599`, 454832}, {235.799`, 463285}, {235.998`, 
467355}, {236.198`, 473789}, {236.399`, 475881}, {236.599`, 
478861}, {236.798`, 479197}, {236.999`, 479826}, {237.199`, 
478605}, {237.399`, 477794}, {237.598`, 477763}, {237.799`, 
478290}, {237.999`, 479078}, {238.198`, 479651}, {238.399`, 
481822}, {238.599`, 481865}, {238.798`, 479795}, {238.999`, 
476638}, {239.199`, 469527}, {239.398`, 464081}, {239.599`, 
455019}, {239.799`, 448143}, {239.998`, 439641}, {240.199`, 
429933}, {240.398`, 421110}, {240.599`, 411717}, {240.799`, 
405048}, {240.998`, 394290}, {241.199`, 389475}, {241.398`, 
380499}, {241.599`, 373441}, {241.799`, 366395}, {241.998`, 
359473}, {242.199`, 353309}, {242.398`, 348918}, {242.599`, 
342246}, {242.798`, 337668}, {242.999`, 333185}, {243.198`, 
327799}, {243.399`, 322453}, {243.598`, 314913}, {243.799`, 
307589}, {243.998`, 298974}, {244.199`, 288987}, {244.398`, 
276684}, {244.599`, 265150}, {244.798`, 252771}, {244.999`, 
239238}, {245.198`, 229405}, {245.399`, 220741}, {245.598`, 
211481}, {245.799`, 201938}, {245.998`, 192817}, {246.199`, 
185288}, {246.399`, 176073}, {246.598`, 167987}, {246.799`, 
160870}, {246.998`, 152968}, {247.199`, 144964}, {247.399`, 
137084}, {247.598`, 130336}, {247.799`, 122953}, {247.998`, 
116106}, {248.199`, 108375}, {248.399`, 102066}, {248.598`, 
96105}, {248.799`, 91330}, {248.999`, 86978}, {249.198`, 
83021}, {249.399`, 80587}, {249.599`, 78638}, {249.798`, 
76445}, {249.999`, 73552}, {250.199`, 69963}, {250.398`, 
65397}, {250.599`, 62634}, {250.799`, 58960}, {250.998`, 
55956}, {251.198`, 52231}, {251.399`, 49522}, {251.599`, 
46220}, {251.798`, 44118}, {251.998`, 41522}, {252.199`, 
38881}, {252.399`, 37668}, {252.598`, 35394}, {252.798`, 
34090}, {252.999`, 32484}, {253.199`, 31128}, {253.399`, 
30198}, {253.598`, 28768}, {253.798`, 28094}, {253.999`, 
27299}, {254.199`, 26216}, {254.399`, 25348}, {254.599`, 
24330}, {254.798`, 24195}, {254.998`, 23133}, {255.199`, 
22500}, {255.399`, 21507}, {255.599`, 20840}, {255.799`, 
19991}, {255.999`, 19558}, {256.198`, 18848}, {256.398`, 
18365}, {256.598`, 17810}, {256.798`, 17337}, {256.998`, 
16601}, {257.199`, 16178}, {257.399`, 15453}, {257.599`, 
14995}, {257.799`, 14558}, {257.999`, 13947}, {258.199`, 
13364}, {258.399`, 12965}, {258.599`, 12451}, {258.799`, 
11744}, {258.999`, 11368}, {259.199`, 10897}, {259.399`, 
10525}, {259.599`, 10177}, {259.799`, 9729}, {259.999`, 
9351}, {260.199`, 8904}, {260.399`, 8533}, {260.599`, 
8310}, {260.799`, 7889}, {260.999`, 7475}, {261.199`, 
7276}, {261.399`, 6904}, {261.599`, 6602}, {261.798`, 
6445}, {261.998`, 6261}, {262.198`, 6040}, {262.398`, 
5706}, {262.599`, 5518}, {262.799`, 5410}, {262.999`, 
5114}, {263.199`, 5006}, {263.399`, 4933}, {263.598`, 
4818}, {263.798`, 4551}, {263.998`, 4581}, {264.199`, 
4253}, {264.399`, 4266}, {264.599`, 4106}, {264.798`, 
4130}, {264.998`, 3937}};

zerotwentyfivemmslit = {{214.999`, 5}, {215.199`, 5}, {215.398`, 
5}, {215.599`, 7}, {215.799`, 9}, {215.998`, 4}, {216.199`, 
13}, {216.399`, 7}, {216.598`, 9}, {216.799`, 14}, {216.999`, 
12}, {217.198`, 26}, {217.398`, 19}, {217.599`, 16}, {217.799`, 
20}, {217.998`, 31}, {218.199`, 18}, {218.399`, 22}, {218.598`, 
15}, {218.798`, 8}, {218.999`, 9}, {219.199`, 14}, {219.399`, 
12}, {219.598`, 43}, {219.798`, 32}, {219.999`, 79}, {220.199`, 
131}, {220.398`, 208}, {220.598`, 284}, {220.799`, 
316}, {220.999`, 396}, {221.199`, 393}, {221.399`, 
492}, {221.598`, 484}, {221.798`, 462}, {221.999`, 
484}, {222.199`, 479}, {222.399`, 426}, {222.599`, 
502}, {222.798`, 514}, {222.998`, 601}, {223.198`, 
685}, {223.399`, 922}, {223.599`, 1306}, {223.799`, 
1740}, {223.999`, 2249}, {224.199`, 2809}, {224.399`, 
3401}, {224.598`, 3976}, {224.798`, 4694}, {224.998`, 
5333}, {225.198`, 5825}, {225.398`, 6576}, {225.598`, 
7318}, {225.799`, 7796}, {225.999`, 8224}, {226.199`, 
8081}, {226.399`, 7815}, {226.599`, 7188}, {226.799`, 
6746}, {226.999`, 6157}, {227.199`, 6187}, {227.399`, 
6503}, {227.599`, 7135}, {227.799`, 8390}, {227.999`, 
10160}, {228.199`, 12054}, {228.399`, 13541}, {228.599`, 
14836}, {228.799`, 15554}, {228.999`, 16642}, {229.199`, 
17074}, {229.398`, 17906}, {229.598`, 18496}, {229.798`, 
18904}, {229.998`, 19375}, {230.198`, 19158}, {230.398`, 
18461}, {230.599`, 17303}, {230.799`, 16445}, {230.999`, 
15966}, {231.199`, 16357}, {231.399`, 17799}, {231.599`, 
19785}, {231.798`, 22918}, {231.998`, 26463}, {232.198`, 
30116}, {232.399`, 32395}, {232.599`, 34679}, {232.799`, 
35349}, {232.999`, 36186}, {233.198`, 36976}, {233.398`, 
36940}, {233.599`, 37210}, {233.799`, 37667}, {233.999`, 
38676}, {234.198`, 39743}, {234.398`, 39677}, {234.599`, 
40314}, {234.799`, 40097}, {234.999`, 37265}, {235.198`, 
34256}, {235.398`, 30700}, {235.599`, 28591}, {235.799`, 
28349}, {235.998`, 30548}, {236.198`, 34986}, {236.399`, 
40854}, {236.599`, 45492}, {236.798`, 49121}, {236.999`, 
52359}, {237.199`, 53112}, {237.399`, 54027}, {237.598`, 
53658}, {237.799`, 53125}, {237.999`, 52272}, {238.198`, 
50846}, {238.399`, 48707}, {238.599`, 47127}, {238.798`, 
44972}, {238.999`, 42868}, {239.199`, 41051}, {239.398`, 
39947}, {239.599`, 38539}, {239.799`, 37167}, {239.998`, 
35682}, {240.199`, 33925}, {240.398`, 32410}, {240.599`, 
32267}, {240.799`, 31819}, {240.998`, 32089}, {241.199`, 
33394}, {241.398`, 34589}, {241.599`, 35103}, {241.799`, 
35280}, {241.998`, 35437}, {242.199`, 35111}, {242.398`, 
34515}, {242.599`, 33712}, {242.798`, 33009}, {242.999`, 
31794}, {243.198`, 30610}, {243.399`, 29591}, {243.598`, 
28583}, {243.799`, 27472}, {243.998`, 26668}, {244.199`, 
25751}, {244.398`, 24963}, {244.599`, 24073}, {244.798`, 
23359}, {244.999`, 22675}, {245.198`, 22192}, {245.399`, 
21190}, {245.598`, 20086}, {245.799`, 19325}, {245.998`, 
17886}, {246.199`, 16184}, {246.399`, 14205}, {246.598`, 
11675}, {246.799`, 9416}, {246.998`, 8302}, {247.199`, 
8128}, {247.399`, 8972}, {247.598`, 9980}, {247.799`, 
10664}, {247.998`, 10691}, {248.199`, 10482}, {248.399`, 
10251}, {248.598`, 9768}, {248.799`, 9090}, {248.999`, 
8627}, {249.198`, 8100}, {249.399`, 7589}, {249.599`, 
7059}, {249.798`, 6567}, {249.999`, 6068}, {250.199`, 
5679}, {250.398`, 5057}, {250.599`, 4801}, {250.799`, 
4480}, {250.998`, 4074}, {251.198`, 3857}, {251.399`, 
3614}, {251.599`, 3424}, {251.798`, 3339}, {251.998`, 
3277}, {252.199`, 3021}, {252.399`, 3033}, {252.598`, 
2923}, {252.798`, 3028}, {252.999`, 2733}, {253.199`, 
2708}, {253.399`, 2628}, {253.598`, 2557}, {253.798`, 
2478}, {253.999`, 2353}, {254.199`, 2206}, {254.399`, 
2122}, {254.599`, 2032}, {254.798`, 1996}, {254.998`, 
1887}, {255.199`, 1872}, {255.399`, 1812}, {255.599`, 
1709}, {255.799`, 1771}, {255.999`, 1827}, {256.198`, 
1644}, {256.398`, 1616}, {256.598`, 1563}, {256.798`, 
1474}, {256.998`, 1419}, {257.199`, 1455}, {257.399`, 
1386}, {257.599`, 1352}, {257.799`, 1248}, {257.999`, 
1270}, {258.199`, 1204}, {258.399`, 1160}, {258.599`, 
1085}, {258.799`, 1059}, {258.999`, 1034}, {259.199`, 
962}, {259.399`, 945}, {259.599`, 880}, {259.799`, 
891}, {259.999`, 805}, {260.199`, 733}, {260.399`, 
706}, {260.599`, 665}, {260.799`, 601}, {260.999`, 
622}, {261.199`, 541}, {261.399`, 558}, {261.599`, 
501}, {261.798`, 473}, {261.998`, 549}, {262.198`, 
458}, {262.398`, 443}, {262.599`, 471}, {262.799`, 
491}, {262.999`, 455}, {263.199`, 410}, {263.399`, 
411}, {263.598`, 405}, {263.798`, 410}, {263.998`, 
373}, {264.199`, 393}, {264.399`, 368}, {264.599`, 
362}, {264.798`, 307}, {264.998`, 336}};
```

and

```
In[54]:= s3 = (3 10^-3)/(.2 10^-9)

Out[54]= 1.5*10^7

In[55]:= s025 = (.25 10^-3)/(.2 10^-9)

Out[55]= 1.25*10^6
```

Comment: Can you make your post more compact, pointing at the essentials?

Comment: @corey979 I hope this is more readable. Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: try defining the function you are trying to minimize as a function of only numeric alpha, `g[alpha_NumericQ] := Total[ ...]` , then use `NMinimize` on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @corey979 for your comment which helped me clarify what I sought, and @george2079 for pointing me in the right direction! After a couple more hours of trials and errors I have finally managed.

I have also decided to change the type of error measurement I wish to minimize. Here is the new code with comments (data as in question):

1. I start by creating an interpolation function from my data set (2D list of wavelengths and counts):

   ```
   f1 := Interpolation[zerotwentyfivemmslit, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
   ```

   the interpolation order is unimportant in the present case.
2. I create a function that integrates this interpolation function with moving central wavelength of the (variable size) integration interval:

   ```
   f[\[Lambda]_, \[Alpha]_] := 1/(\[Alpha] s025 10^9)Quiet@ N@Integrate[f1[\[Lambda]prime], {\[Lambda]prime, \[Lambda] - (\[Alpha] s3)/
    2 10^9, \[Lambda] + (\[Alpha] s3)/2 10^9}];
   ```

   in data analysis terms, I smooth my function with a top hat function of width $\alpha$.
3. I then create a function that only evaluates if its $\alpha$ argument is a numeric quantity, and allows me to fit any data set:

   ```
   g[\[Alpha]_?NumericQ,list_] := \[Sqrt]Mean[MapThread[(#1 - #2)^2 &,{list[[All, 2]],Table[f[\[Lambda], \[Alpha]], {\[Lambda],Round[list[[1, 1]],.01], Round[list[[Length[list], 1]], .01],Round[list[[2, 1]] - list[[1, 1]], .01]}]}]];
   ```

   Note that, being the data set I wish to fit a 2D list (wavelengths and counts), I need to create a data set of same dimensions from the result of my integration (hence the Table[] command and the rounding of its bounds).

Also, I have decided to Minimize the least square values of my fitting (contrarily to what was stated in the question).

4. I can then use Minimize to find the fitting parameter $\alpha$:

   ```
   NMinimize[{g[\[Alpha],threemmslit], \[Alpha] >= 5 10^-7 && \[Alpha] <= 5 10^-6}, {\[Alpha]}]
   ```

Final result:

```
    In[36]:= NMinimize[{g[\[Alpha],threemmslit], \[Alpha] >= 5 10^-7 && \[Alpha] <=5 10^-6}, {\[Alpha]}] // AbsoluteTiming

    Out[36]= {453.795, {16217.5, {\[Alpha] -> 2.48017*10^-6}}}
```

Yeah... it takes a while to evaluate (I have a 3yold i5) and I have six data sets to fit. But it's pretty neat and works!

Comment: if you happen to have an idea of how to optimize the evaluation time, I'm open to suggestions!